# OpenSpout \ Reader \ Exception \ InvalidValueException in Spatie\SimpleExcel\SimpleExcelReader

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to download excel file,  one column has date format. Almost cell values have correct date format, but some cells have an incorrect format.

As a result of running the script I get an error `OpenSpout \ Reader \ Exception \ InvalidValueException`

```
$excel = \Spatie\SimpleExcel\SimpleExcelReader::create($path)->getRows();
        foreach($excel->chunk(1000) as $rows) {
            $this->setToDatabase($rows->toArray());
        }
```

Haw can I get ignore this cells?

Comment: what is `setToDatabase()`? post full error

Comment: @francisco Error gone before this function. SimpleExcelReader try to get or format value datatime (becouse culumn in excel has date format). End if cell another format - i get InvalidValueException.

Comment: format the date to "dd/mm/yyyy" before sending to excel.